# How to simulate behavior of "curl -s --negotiate -u:anyUser url" programmatically ?

Tags: java, http, spnego

I want to send http request like command "curl -s --negotiate -u:anyUser url" for spnego enabled service. How can I implement it programmatically ? Java implementation should be better.

Comment: You should at least show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` supports it out of the box.